# Jekyll/Liquid ignoring raw input tag, failing

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm running Jekyll version 1.5.0 on Ruby version ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161).

I'm trying to migrate an old site that has hundreds of instances of raw tags so that jekyll/liquid won't try to parse those. For example:

```
{% raw %}
  {% for img in imgs %}
    {% img.title img.source %}
{% endraw %}
```

That used to work fine under the old version, but now it tries to parse whatever is inside of the raw tags which is causing a million (ok, maybe just a couple dozen or so) errors and exceptions. The RawTag plugin is where it's supposed to and it's "working".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

And if you close the for loop ?

```
{% raw %}
  {% for img in imgs %}
    {% img.title img.source %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: Turns out there was a rogue plug-in installed that was double parsing the input blocks :/ Thanks for help though.